# Publish subscriber pattern using instance based decorators 'this' is always undefined

Tags: javascript, decorator

```
class Observable {
    constructor() {
        this.handlers = [];
    }

    publish(value) {
        this.handlers.forEach(handler => {
            handler(value);
        });
    }

    subscribe(callback) {
        this.handlers.push(callback);
    }
}

const concreteObserver = new Observable();

 function Subscribe(observable) {
      return function functionDescriptor(target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
          observable.subscribe(target[propertyKey]);
          return descriptor;
      }
 }

 class MyClass {   

     constructor(){
        this.x = 5;
     }

     @Subscribe(concreteObserver)
     subsribeToValue(value) {     
       console.log(this.x); // undefined
     }
 }
```

As you can see, the `subscribe` function is called each time, someone calls `concreteObserver.publish()` however, when you call `observable.subscribe(target[propertyKey]);` then 'this' becomes undefined.

I also tried overriding the descriptor getter, and calling that one, but i still get undefined. On classes i was able to wrap a function by calling `target.prototype.functionName`.

This works when i know what the function name will be called, but the function name for `@Subscribe` can be arbitrary, so i can't use it on a class level decorator unless i use Reflection to detect all the annotations of the class.

---

**EDIT**

Tried so far

`observable.subscribe(target[propertyKey].bind(this));`

which returns undefined, subscribe has the right context in this case.

`observable.subscribe(data => descriptor.value.apply(this, data));` also has 'this' as undefined

```
descriptor.value = function(){
   console.log(this); //undefined 
}

descriptor.get = function(){
   console.log(this); //undefined
}
```

---

The solution i came up with. Since it is only possible to get the instance of a class in the class decorator, then that is where `this` can be used properly, in the the subscribe function i tell what function i should subscribe to, then in the ClassDecorator i iterate through each method to determine if they have `__subscribeFunction` in their prototype and thus subscribe to the method while binding `instance`

```
class Observable {
    constructor() {
        this.handlers = [];
    }

    publish(value) {
        this.handlers.forEach(handler => {
            handler(value);
        });
    }

    subscribe(callback) {
        this.handlers.push(callback);
    }
}

const concreteObserver = new Observable();

function ClassDecorator(target) {
    const originalTarget = target;

    const Override = function (...args) {
        const instance = originalTarget.apply(this, args);

        Object.values(instance.__proto__).forEach(method => {
            const observableFunction = method.prototype.__subscribeFunction;
            if (observableFunction) {
                observableFunction.subscribe(method.bind(instance));
            }
        });
        return instance;
    };

    Override.prototype = originalTarget.prototype;
    customElements.define(elementName, target);
    return Override;
}

 function Subscribe(observable) {
      return function functionDescriptor(target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
          target[propertyKey].prototype.__subscribeFunction = observable;
      }
 }

 @ClassDecorator
 class MyClass {   

     constructor(){
        this.x = 5;
     }

     @Subscribe(concreteObserver)
     subsribeToValue(value) {     
       console.log(this.x); // 5
     }
 }
```

Comment: Well, the call `handler(value);` does not provide any `this` context, [so it's `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). What do you expect, the `Observable` instance, the `MyClass` instance, or something else?

Comment: the handler set this correctly, however subscribeToValue of this is undefined, even when binding this

Comment: Where and how exactly did you try to bind something?

Comment: Calling subscribe inside the decorator, seems to be the problem, but i somehow have to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because the decorator is called when the class itself is constructed, but before any instance is created. Since there's no instance, there can't be a `this` – you only have access to the prototype, but class properties aren't on the prototype (unlike methods).

You can verify this using this example:

```
function Example() {
    console.log("@Example initialized");
    return function exampleDescriptior(target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
        console.log("@Example called");
    }
}

console.log("Before declaring class");
class Test {
    @Example()
    public test() {}
}
console.log("After declaring class");

console.log("Before creating instance");
const test = new Test();
console.log("After creating instance");

console.log("Before calling method");
test.test();
console.log("After calling method");
```

which yields the output

```
Before declaring class
@Example initialized
@Example called
After declaring class
Before creating instance
After creating instance
Before calling method
After calling method
```

---

That said, what you *can* do is write another decorator applied on, say, class level which proxies the constructor. If your `@Subscribe` annotation stores some meta-data on the prototype, the class decorator could then look for it and do the actual wiring. So getting something like

```
@AutoSubscribe()
class MyClass {
  @Subscribe(observer)
  subscribe(value) {
    console.log(this.x);
  }
}
```

to work should be possible. In fact, you could maybe even get rid of the second decorator by proxying the constructor from the `@Subscribe` decorator, but you'd still have to store metadata that you can look through during instantiation.

Comment: This was the solution i was afraid that i had to go with, then my class annotation basically becomes a instance factory for method annotations

Comment: @Pavlo Actually, it might be possible to change the descriptor of the constructor from the method-level decorator as well (`target.constructor`). I haven't tried it, but it'd be worth a shot. It'd save you the second decorator, but not the whole lookup metadata process. But using reflect-metadata that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: `const original = target.constructor.prototype[propertyKey];

        target.constructor.prototype[propertyKey] = function (data: any) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(this); // undefined
            original(data).bind(this);
        };

        observable.subscribe(target[propertyKey]);
        // observable.subscribe(target.constructor.prototype[propertyKey]);`

Doesn't work either

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. I meant you can basically do what the class decorator would have to do from the method decorator. It would still involve storing some metadata, though. An example for overwriting the constructor is here: https://gist.github.com/remojansen/16c661a7afd68e22ac6e